# Hive: Bucketed table sanity check

Tags: hadoop, hive

How can I check if a partition of a bucketed table is properly bucketed or not? Just checking the number of files in partition equals number of buckets of table doesn't seem to be enough. How can I check whether all the rows in every bucket belong to that bucket only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following will be helpful

```
DESCRIBE EXTENDED page_view PARTITION (ds='2008-08-08');
```

i got it from here

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial

Comment: DESCRIBE EXTENDED just returns metadata information. How can I make sure that data is properly bucketed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will work but i think if table is cluseretd by columns a,b into n buckets then `hash(a,b)%n` is the bucket number (you can see it in the file name in hdfs).

If you are not sure, you can always insert oevrwrite the partition selecting from itself and setting `hive.force.bucketing` to true.

Answer (score 0):

if the bucket is partitioned on colA, then you can verify the count for each bucket.
Suppose we are storing years in colA, so each bucket will have rows for a particular year only. We can verify this by running and see if all the buckets have rows for a single year only.

```
SELECT distinct Year FROM bucketed_table tablesample(bucket 1 out of Y on year);
SELECT distinct Year FROM bucketed_table tablesample(bucket 2 out of Y on year);
```

Also we can verify the count by running a query using where clause.
`SELECT count(*) FROM bucketed_table tablesample(bucket 1 out of Y on year);` `//suppose that bucket 1 stores year X`

```
SELECT count(*) FROM bucketed_table where year=X;
```

This is again is not a sure-shot way for checking the correctness of your hvie buckets but yes if you know the data well and you can use this strategy to verify your tables.